# display column that is summation of other column values where intermediate values come from inner selects

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following query. 2 columns are results of inner selects (select1 and select2). How to display additional column (select1+select2) that contains summation of the values in the 2 columns coming from the inner selects?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableC.something, tableD.something,
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS result1
FROM tableA) AS select1,

(SELECT SUM(number) AS result2
FROM tableB) AS select2,

select1+select2
FROM tableC
RIGHT JOIN tableD
ON tableD.p_id=tableC.id
WHERE tableC.something1=1
AND tableD.something=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a CTE or subquery:

```
with cte as (
      SELECT DISTINCT tableC.something, tableD.something,
             (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableA) AS select1,
             (SELECT SUM(number) FROM tableB) AS select2,

      FROM tableC JOIN
           tableD
           ON tableD.p_id=tableC.id
      WHERE tableC.something1 = 1 AND tableD.something = 1
     )
select cte.*, select1 + select2
from cte;
```

Note that I changed the `right join` to an `inner join`.  Your `where` clause turns it into an `inner join` anyway, so specifying an outer join is misleading.

EDIT:

I would really write this query moving the subqueries to the `from` clause:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT tableC.something, tableD.something,
             a.select1, b.select2, a.select1 + b.select2
      FROM tableC JOIN
           tableD
           ON tableD.p_id = tableC.id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(id) as select1 FROM tableA) a CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT SUM(number) as select2 FROM tableB) b 
      WHERE tableC.something1 = 1 AND tableD.something = 1
```